# Flannel compatiblity with etcd v3.0

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, flannel, etcd3

I am planning to migrate our Kubernetes instance to etcd v3.
Do you know if Flannel will work with etcd v3?

Answer (score 0):

From my deployment process, flannel is uncompatiblity with etcd v3.0 now(2019/09/06). I am finding a way to
 handle this, when I starting flannel it throws this error:

```
E0908 20:05:41.432715   28891 main.go:382] Couldn't fetch network config: 100: Key not found (/kube-centos)
```